# G729 codec not seen in settings

Tags: java, android, linphone

I downloaded linphone git and ran `make BUILD_G729=1` but i dont see g729 option in settings anywhere. Why is this did i do something wrong?

http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html

It built successfully and i put it on my droid but no options to enable g729 in sight.

I am compiling for android is there anything i missed or have to do extra? I have been lost at this for days. How can i get g729 codec on my linphone android app?